# Stub ActiveJob with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob

I have an active job `SubscribeUserToMailingListJob` that updates my Mailchimp list everytime a user is created using an after_commit callback.

When I run my test suite, these updates are fired, causing a lot of "cannot find Model with ID=1234" errors to be posted to Rollbar. I would like to stub out `SubscribeUserToMailingListJob` when creating fake users for testing, without affecting the test for the job itself.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it you can stub the method that is used in the after_commit 
with rspec-mocks https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class

You can do it just with:
`Model.any_instance.stubs(:the_after_commit_method)`

Answer (score 0):

Note: The new syntax is

```
allow(User).to receive(:find_by).and_return(user)
```